# How to generate a bitcoin public key from an existing private key using openssl?

Tags: private-key, public-key, openssl

I want to generate bitcoin priv/pub key manually.
I generated random binary numbers by flipping some coins and converted them to hex.

Now,I got a bitcoin private key
in hex:`d1267088f0defab13969dd34c899d28268119cf9e68f3856d0ee9b581f5a1bca`

in WIF:`L4EGhR5Fdon96W2zepTAE3CxtayBqiN3v2pBmkB9dxG4r8JaVKf2`

how to gerate Public Key using openssl command line in linux?

I tried to use

```
openssl ec -in priv_key.pem -pubout
```

but terminal said: unable to load Key, and lots error file uris.

Maby I got something wrong with PEM private key format.

The priv_key.pem ,I converted private key hex to base64 format.

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
ZDEyNjcwODhmMGRlZmFiMTM5NjlkZDM0Yzg5OWQyODI2ODExOWNmOWU2OGYzODU2
ZDBlZTliNTgxZjVhMWJjYQ==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: The SECG format for EC privatekey used by OpenSSL is quite different from just the raw bits/number 'd' used in Bitcoin. See crossdupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48101258/how-to-convert-an-ecdsa-key-to-pem-format -- where my answer is based on https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/66594/ but that requires both privatekey and publickey and you apparently don't have publickey (yet; my answer derives it).

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSL will compute a public key corresponding to a private key, try:

```
$ openssl ec -in private_key.openssl.pem -text
```

There must be correct input provided to OpenSSL. It is not enough to convert private key from hex string to base64 in order for it to be accepted by OpenSSL. There must be eliptic curve parameters included in the .pem file, like shown in the short script:

> https://gist.github.com/vkobel/52048e12d8930ef63930949a717ddcbf